# Append a line after found line after first occurrence with sed

Tags: batch-file, sed

i'm trying to insert with batch file a line after the first match with sed.

```
    sed -i "/ProjectReference/a %newLine%" "%projectPath%\****\****.cs"
```

This is working, but it insert a line after all occurrences.

I've tried with:

```
    sed -i "0,/ProjectReference/a %newLine%" "%projectPath%\****\****.cs"
```

but it insets a line after every row.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: When I run command `sed '0,/your_text/a New_Line_Here.../'  Input_file` it worked fine for me. Which version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sed 4.2.1

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Windows 10 PRO

Comment: using GNU sed you need the correct syntax. use single quotes like below. I do not have gnu sed, so you'll have to test. `sed -i '/ProjectReference/a %newline%'`

Comment: I've tried this: `set newLine="^<ProjectReference Include=\"\.\.\\\.\.\\\.\.\\\.\.\\\.\.\\****\\*****\\****\\****\\****.***\" /^>"`
`sed -i '0,/ProjectReference/a %newLine%' "%projectPath%\****\****.***"`
 and i had an error: `sed: expression - e #1, char 1: unknown command ''`